Why does a java servlet retain bad form entries?
We have a special search page in a java web app running on a Tomcat 9 server. The page uses a form with a few <input> tags of type "text". During some testing I was doing, I found a strange occurrence:
I input some text in one of the text boxes and it causes an error in the java code--it then runs the code in the catch block. After executing that code and returning the response to the servlet, it shows the expected error page. However, if I leave the page and come back to it in any way, it still shows the error page! I could even exit the application (leaving Tomcat running) and reenter, and it would still show the same error page. When we had it deployed on a shared test server, other users would also see the same error page if they tried to access the search page. When I restart Tomcat, the error page would not immediately appear on the search page (until I test the bad entry in a text box again).
We handled it by clearing out the text boxes in the form in the catch block.
My question is why does the servlet retain those values entered? Or is it a Tomcat thing?

Sounds like you store these things in static  variables perhaps - your claim is incorrect (neither java, nor tomcat, nor 'web forms' share a form submit with others, and it should be obvious why, that'd be silly, and a massive security issue). It's possible you really are witnessing it, but then that's because you've messed something up. Without code to look at, we can't help you.

The problem could be caused not only by static variables but also by instance variables in the servlet that handles the form. Servlets are not created per request - a servlet is created once and then handles all requests. That means that instance variables in a servlet are shared between requests.
